# Getting {switch='A|B'} to work within relationship tag

Tags: templates, relationships, switch

I have the following code:

```
  {staff_member_groups}
    <h2>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_heading}</h2>
    <ul class="staff_member_groups">
      {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
        <li class="{switch='odd|even'}">
          <img src="{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_portrait}">
          <h3>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:title}</h3>
          <p class="meta">
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_position}
          </p>
          <p>
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_titles}
          </p>
        </li>
      {/staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
    </ul>
  {/staff_member_groups}
```

which renders correctly except for the fact that `{switch='odd|even'}` returns `odd` on every list item. Is there a way to get this functionality while looping through a relationship tag?

**Edit:** I should clarify: `{staff_member_groups}` is a grid field, with `{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}` being the relationship field within the grid field.

**Edit #2:** I’ve found the solution (still new around here, SE won’t let me answer my own questions really quickly yet). `{switch='odd|even'}` needs to be namespaced so that it switches within the context of the relationship field, like so: `{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:switch='odd|even'}`. Otherwise, `{switch='odd|even'}` is going by the larger context of the entries tag that surrounds this template.

For clarity, my final block of code looks like this:

```
  {staff_member_groups}
    <h2>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_heading}</h2>
    <ul class="staff_member_groups">
      {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
        <li class="{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:switch='odd|even'}">
          <img src="{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_portrait}">
          <h3>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:title}</h3>
          <p class="meta">
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_position}
          </p>
          <p>
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_titles}
          </p>
        </li>
      {/staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
    </ul>
  {/staff_member_groups}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. When you are able to, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I sure will, @JeremyGimbel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve found the solution: `{switch='odd|even'}` needs to be namespaced so that it switches within the context of the relationship field, like so:

`{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:switch='odd|even'}`

Otherwise, `{switch='odd|even'}` is going by the larger context of the entries tag that surrounds this template.

For clarity, my final block of code looks like this:

```
  {staff_member_groups}
    <h2>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_heading}</h2>
    <ul class="staff_member_groups">
      {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
        <li class="{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:switch='odd|even'}">
          <img src="{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_portrait}">
          <h3>{staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:title}</h3>
          <p class="meta">
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_position}
          </p>
          <p>
            {staff_member_groups:staff_group_members:staff_titles}
          </p>
        </li>
      {/staff_member_groups:staff_group_members}
    </ul>
  {/staff_member_groups}
```

Comment: Possibly worth noting that this applies to {count} as well.